# How to put a texture on some part of a mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to put a texture (square RGBA array) on some part of a mesh (say a sphere). How to achieve this in Three.js? Thanks for help!

Here is a not-working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dongli/ykjovrbd/1/). For example, I would like to put the texture on 0~10E, -5S~5N region. Should I use `glsl` to do such task? It seems Three.js does not provide such function.

```
const width = 400, height = 300, radians = Math.PI / 180

// Create a sample data.
var nx = 360, ny = 180
var data = new Uint8Array(4 * nx * ny)
for (var i = 0; i < nx * ny; i += 4) {
  data[i+0] = 255
  data[i+1] = 0
  data[i+2] = 0
  data[i+3] = 122
}

var scene, camera, renderer, light, geometry, texture, material, sphere

scene = new THREE.Scene()
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-width / 2, width / 2, height / 2, -height / 2, 0.1, 10000)
camera.position.z = 500

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
renderer.setClearColor('white', 1)
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

light = new THREE.HemisphereLight('#fff', '#666', 1.5)
light.position.set(0, 500, 0)
scene.add(light)

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(120, 20, 20, 0, 90 * radians, 60 * radians, 60 * radians)
texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, nx, ny, THREE.RGBAFormat)
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
texture.needsUpdate = true
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, wireframe: true })
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(sphere)

function render () {
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.01
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}
render(
```

)

Comment: Can you post some code ? This can be done in many different ways.

Comment: @Hesha I have added an example code. Thanks!

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/o83gzmhz/1/

Comment: @MartyBoggs Sorry, it seems the same as the original one. What I want is the texture covers part of the sphere.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ykjovrbd/4/

Comment: @WestLangley Yes, I want this. I also found my stupid error last night. Thanks! I came up with this partial mesh idea, and are there any other better options?

Comment: What you are doing seems reasonable.